# How do i solve a localStorage.getItem() error?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to get a user's data when he/she logs into a database (firestore), using a form. I am using the JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem()) method to get the user's data when he logs in or return null when the user logs out. So I wrote this inside my code:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
```

But i keep getting this error which says "method ...localStorage.getItem() has an argument type of 'string | null'..."

is there something i am missing?

Below is my full code:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Webuser } from './webuser';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
//import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
//import 'firebase/auth';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // This saves logged in user data

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore, // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service is called to remove outside scope warnings
    ) {
       /* Saving user data in local storage when 
         logged in and setting up null when logged out */

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })

   }

   // Login with email/password
   Login(email: string, password: string) {
     return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
     .then((result) => {
       this.ngZone.run(() => {
         this.router.navigate(['']);
       });
       this.SetUserData(result.user);
     }).catch((error) => {
       window.alert(error.message);
     })
   }

   // Signup with email/password
   SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      // Here we call the SendVerificationMail() method when a user signs up and returns promise
      this.SendVerificationMail();
      this.SetUserData(result.user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error.message);
    })
   }

   // Send email verification when user signs up
   SendVerificationMail() {
     return this.afAuth.currentUser.then(u => u.sendEmailVerification())
     .then(() => {
       this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
     })
   }

   // Reset Forgotten password
   ForgotPasword(passwordResetEmail: string) {
     return this.afAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(passwordResetEmail)
     .then(() => {
       window.alert('Password reset email sent to the email you provided. Please check your inbox');

     }).catch((error) => {
       window.alert(error);
     })
   }

   // This returns true when user email is verified and user is logged in
   get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
     const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
     return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false)
   }

   /* Setting up user data when login with username/password, 
      sign up with username/password in Firestore database using 
      AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */

      SetUserData(user: any) {
        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc('users/${user.uid}');
        const userData: Webuser ={
          uId: user.uid,
          name: user.name,
          emailVerified: user.emailVerified
        }
        return userRef.set(userData, {
          merge: true
        })
      }

      // Signing out a user

      SignOut() {
        return this.afAuth.signOut().then(() => {
          localStorage.removeItem('user');
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        })
      }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I followed the example given here: https://www.positronx.io/full-angular-7-firebase-authentication-system/

Comment: As the error says, `JSON.parse` accepts a `string` while `localStorage.getItems` returns `string | null`, so you must check that the value fetched from the `localStorage` is not `null` before parsing it.

Comment: Thanks, Denis. I was able to solve it. I changed those JSON lines from the former to this:  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') ?? ' ') and i also changed the localStorage.setItem('user', null) to localStorage.setItem('user',' '). This cleared all my errors.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good solution to me, why don't parse the value of `user` only if there is one rather than fallback to a default value? Furthermore, `''` is not a valid JSON value so `JSON.parse('')` throws an error.

Comment: @Andrecon - to second Denis: the best guiding principle you can have is to *exit as early as possible* (aka shortcircuit). Just return `false` if there is no "user" item in localStorage and forget about it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Denis and Oleg. I have tried all you both opined and none worked. Denis, I did parse the value of user only and i git an error which says it requires two arguments but instead it got one.

Comment: `(getItem('user')`  always returns either `null` or `string`. Hence the `string | null` part. `JSON.parse` can *only* parse strings. therefore you either need (1) a sensible default; (2) a statement allowing the type to be narrowed to `string`; (3) rework to return as soon as result of `getItem` is falsy

Comment: @OlegValter I get that (getItem('user') always returns either a string or null. On vscode, i wrote only (getItem('user')) but it is flagged as an error. That was the reason i modified the code. i don't know if it is allowed for one to inbox something to someone on this forum, i would've liked to send my edited code to you for preview.

Comment: @Andrecon - we can't look at what we can't see :) Just update the question  - since there are no answers, you will not be invalidating any

Comment: localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));  What is a purpose of last line when value is not assigned and used? Either way, break it down, first get it from storage check if not null then parse

Comment: @Nonik I did that but it didn't work.